# Are any descriptions of Rudra's aspect?

Tags: shiva, rudra, pashupata-shaivism

Are any descriptions of Rudra's aspect ? If yes, where we can find them?

Comment: what do you mean by aspect? Did you mean Saumya and Raudra aspect.../ Ghora-Aghora aspect...?...

Comment: Any description of Rudra from the scriptures. For example does he has horns? does he wear tiger skin? etc..

Comment: There are 11 Rudras. About which Rudra are you talking?

Comment: All of them...i am searching their aspects.

Comment: @LuckyPashu if you are really interested in in-depth exploration and have the patience to read then please try "Sanatana Dhara Rudra Shiva across Vedas and Itihasa" in Google. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the shivopasana mantra of the Krishna yajurveda Mahanarayanaya Upanishad. It describes and covers the 5 primary aspects of shiva/rudra.

Rudra/Shiva is of 5 aspects sadyojata, ghora/aghora, vamadeva, tatpurusha, ishaana.

Sadyojata: source of all existence
Vamadeva: the most beautiful and effulgent
Aghora/Ghora: terrifying and non terrifying
tatpurusha: the Supreme Personality/Purusha
Ishaana: the supreme ruler and creator of all beings

His specific form is described as the following:
namo hiraNya-baahave hiraNya-varNaaya hiraNya-ruupaya hiraNya-pataye
ambikaapataya umaa-pataye pashu pataye namo namah

Namaha to the One who has golden hands ( hiraNya-baahave ) ; who is the golden hue or whose speech is charming ( varNa means colour or word ) ; who is of golden form ( ruupa ) or whose form is charming ; who is Lord ( pataye ) of wealth and gold ; who is the Lord of Mother Ambika and Lord of Uma and who is the Lord of all beings ( pashu : animals )

And from the rudram he is described as the following:  om namaste astu bhagavan visvesvaraya mahadevaya

tryambakaya tripurantakaya trikalagni-kalaya

kalagnirudraya neelakanthaya mrutyunjayaya

sarveshvaraya sadashivaya shrimanmahadevaya namah

Om. Oh, Bhagavan, may this salutation be unto you who is the Lord of the universe, the great God, the three-eyed, the destroyer of demon Tripura, who is the Sandya time when three fires are lit, the Rudra that is the fire that consumes the universe, the blue-necked, the conqueror of death, the Lord of all, the ever-auspicious one.  Salutations unto the glorious great Lord.

Hope above helps sources are Shivopasana Mantra from Krishna Yajurveda and Sri Rudram.